# How can get the "options" field from Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get the "options" field from the transaction details using the IPN. I mean, I don't know which IPN variable is the options column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @close-voter Too broad? Come off it. The question has *one* answer, maybe two.

Answer (score 0):

This is all defined in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/). Specifically, you get `option_name1, option_selection1` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes I'm getting the option_name1 and option_selection1 and they're empty. Same in option_name2 and option_selection2.

Comment: Are you *sending* them, in the form data?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending: on1, os1, os0, on2, os2. Besides when I check the transaction detail from the Paypal History tab, I can see the values, so I assume I'm sending them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my self. The correct field is "option_selection1_1" (option_name1_1, option_name2_1...), I think that the second "1" should be the number of the item, I must used even with only one item. I don't know why Paypal doesn't fix this in the official documentation.